# Obtaining the percentile 95 of a matrix and then plotting it

Tags: r, matlab, statistics, quantile

EDIT:
I have been asked to add more detail. Originally I have a 360x180 matrix, and in it there are data of E-P values, these values stand for Evaporation (E) and Precipitation (P), and they basically indicate sources (E-P>0) and sinks(E-P<0) of moisture. In order to obtain the most important sources of moisture I have to take only the positive values, and I want to obtain the percentile 95 of these values, then plot the values which are above this threshold, since I wanted to do a reproducible example I used the `peaks` data:

I have done this in MATLAB but if it can be made on R it works for me as well.

I have an example 49x49 matrix like this:

```
a = peaks; 
pcolor(a);
caxis([-10 10]); 
cbh=colorbar('v');
set(cbh,'YTick',(-10:1:10))
```

And it shows something like this [image]

What I want to do is to obtain the percentile 95 of only the positive values, and then plotting them.

How can I do this? and also, what would it be better: To replace all the values less than zero with 0's or Nan's??

Comment: I have added more detail, hopping that it makes it more clear.

Comment: I think the question is clear now, voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the statistics toolbox, you can use the function [`prctile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prctile.html) to obtain a percentile. I don't have this toolbox, so I wrote [my own version (a long time ago) based on the code for the function `median`](https://www.crisluengo.net/wp-content/uploads/percentile.m). With either `prctile` or `percentile` you can do:

```matlab
a = peaks;
t = percentile(a(a>0),95);
b = a > t;

subplot(1,2,1)
pcolor(a);
subplot(1,2,2)
pcolor(b);
```

`a(a>0)` is a vector with all the positive values in `a`. `t` is the 95th percentile of this vector.

[image: output of code above]